# Biztalk MQSeries MQSC context Property MQMD_PutApplName issue

Tags: ibm-mq, biztalk, biztalk-2016

We are using BizTalk 2016 and MQSC adapter to send message to IBM MQ. We wanted to set MQMD_PutApplName property which we passed the value via Orchestration/Pipeline Component and we could see BizTalk is sending the value for MQMD_PutApplName property as shown below.
[image]

When we checked in MQ side it takes the default value as shown below and not taking the value BizTalk is sending.
[image]

Looks there is issue with BizTalk 2016 MQSC adapter so could anyone suggest on this issue and how to get the put app name value in MQ in BizTalk 2016

Comment: MQ has given all the permission needed for BizTalk user group to set the context values in MQ. But still BizTalk MQSC adapter is unable to set the put app name in MQ. We are facing this issue in BizTalk 2016 version only whereas BizTalk 2010 is working fine and able to se the context values. Please let me know if any extra configuration needed for BizTalk 2016 to set the MQ context values in MQ

Answer (score 0):

In order to **set** the values of context fields in the `MQMD` header, you need to be granted a particular authority or the queue manager will ignore, and over-write, what you wrote in there. You also need to explicitly ask to do this.

In MQ API parlance, asking to set the values in these context fields is done by using the Open Option `MQOO_SET_ALL_CONTEXT`

I don't know BizTalk configuration, it is there any setting that sounds like "Set Context"? Also, the user ID that you are running this program with, is it in the `mqm` group? If not, what authorities does it have granted on the queue manager?

Try issuing this MQSC command to learn the answer to that.

```
DISPLAY AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QMGR)
```

**Further Reading**

- [Message context](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=messages-message-context)

Comment: MQ has given all the permission needed for BizTalk user group to set the context values in MQ. But still BizTalk MQSC adapter is unable to set the put app name in MQ. We are facing this issue in BizTalk 2016 version only whereas BizTalk 2010 is working fine and able to se the context values. Please let me know if any extra configuration needed for BizTalk 2016 to set the MQ context values in MQ

Comment: Fair enough - I'll bow out then and hope that a BizTalk 2016 expert sees your question - my expertise only extends to IBM MQ side of things. I did try looking in the BizTalk doco online but found nothing helpful. Good Luck.